# Cannot sort an array list using Collections.sort after implementing Comparable

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, comparable, compareto

As the title suggests, I am trying to Sort my ArrayList of objects, and those objects have implemented comparable and have overriden CompareTo

However when I got to sort my arraylist i get this error [image]
I can't seem to understand why I am getting this problem? Can anybody help?

ItemList Class:

```
package stories.cs2800;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ItemList extends AbstractListModel<Item> {

  private ArrayList<Item> items;

  /**
   * Constructor that initializes the array list.
   */
  public ItemList() {
    items = new ArrayList<Item>();
  }

  @Override
  public int getSize() {
    return items.size();
  }

  /**
   * Method to get item based on the index.
   * @param argIndex - Takes parameter of type int. 
   * @return  Returns item at the index.
   */
  @Override
  public Item getElementAt(int argIndex) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (argIndex < 0 || argIndex >= items.size()) {
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    return items.get(argIndex);
  }

  /**
   * Method that gets and Item element based on the name.
   * 
   * @param  argName - takes parameter of type String.
   * @return  Returns the entire item object if name matches, else null.
   */
  public Item getElementByName(String argName) {
    for (Item i : items) {
      if (i.getName().equals(argName)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * Method to add another Item into the array list.
   * @param  Takes parameter of type item.
   * @see ArrayList#add
   */
  public void add(Item next) {
    items.add(next);
    Collections.sort(items);
  }

  /**
   * Boolean method to check if list contains the item of type Item.
   * 
   * @param Takes parameter of type item.
   * @return  returns boolean value of true or false if item is contained.
   */
  public Boolean contains(Item argItem) {
    return items.contains(argItem);
  }

  /**
   * Boolean method remove to remove item of type Item from list.
   * 
   * @param Takes parameter of type Item.
   * @return  returns boolean value of true or false if item is removed.
   */
  public Boolean remove(Item argItem) {
    return items.remove(argItem);
  }

  /**
   * Boolean method that removes and item based on its index.
   * 
   * @argIndex  Takes a parameter of type int. 
   * @return returns boolean value of true or false if item was removed based on index.
   */
  public Boolean remove(int argIndex) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (argIndex < 0 || argIndex >= items.size()) {
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    return items.remove(items.get(argIndex));
  }

  /**
   * Method to find the index of an item object.
   * 
   * @param  Takes parameter of type Item.
   * @return  Returns item index based on the item object entered.
   */
  public int indexOf(Item argItem) {
    return items.indexOf(argItem);
  }

  /**
   * Method to check if item changed.
   * 
   * @param  Takes parameter of type Item.
   */
  public void changed(Item argItem) {
    fireContentsChanged(this, items.indexOf(items), items.indexOf(items));
    /*Method called when one or more items have changed */
  }
}
```

SingleItem Class:

```
  package stories.cs2800
  public class SingleItem implements Comparable<Item>, Item {

  private String name;
  private float value;
  private Item child;

  /**
   * Constructor for the SingleItem object. 
   *
   * @param argName   Stores the name that is set in constructor
   * @param argValue  Stores the float value that is set in Constructor
   * @param argChild  Stores the value of the child element
  */
  public SingleItem(String argName, float argValue, Item argChild) {
    name = argName;
    value = argValue;
    child = argChild;
  }

  /**
   * Getter method to get the value of the name variable.
   *
   * @return returns the name
   */
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  /**
   * Getter method to get the value of the Float variable.
   *
   * @return  value set in the value variable
   *
   */
  @Override
  public Float getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

  /**
   * Setter method to set the value of the Float - No return type.
   * @param argFloat - Takes parameter of type Float using Wrapper class.
   */
  @Override
  public void setValue(Float argFloat) {
    this.value = argFloat;
  }

  /**
   * Method to get the description.
   *
   * @return  Returns the a string with the description
   */
  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
    return "Single items have no description";
  }

  /**
   * Getter method for child element.
   * 
   * @return returns the value of child element
   */
  public Item getChild() {
    return this.child;
  }

  /**
   * Method for adding items.
   * @param child - Takes parameter of type Item.
   * @return  Returns Exception when child is null.
   *
   */

  @Override
  public void add(Item child) {
    if (this.child != null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    this.child = child;
  }

  /**
   * Method for ItemVisitor.
   * @param argVisitor - Takes parameter of ItemVisitor to add current class.
   * @return  Currently no valid method!.
   *
   */
  @Override
  public <T> void accept(ItemVisitor<T> argVisitor) {
    argVisitor.add(this);
  }

  /**
   * Method that takes Boolean as a parameter.
   * @param argBool - Takes parameter of type boolean.
   * @return  Returns exception.
   */
  @Override
  public void open(boolean argBool) throws IllegalStateException {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
  }

  /**
   * Method that compares name to name entered as a parameter.
   * @param item - Takes parameter of type item.
   * @return Returns an int based on comparison of name. E.g. 0 = same, 1 = different.
   */
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Item item) {
    return this.name.compareTo(item.getName());
  }

  /**
   * Method to check if Open.
   * 
   * @return Always returns true.
   */
  @Override
  public boolean isOpen() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    SingleItem other = (SingleItem) obj;
    if (name == null) {
      if (other.name != null) {
        return false;
      }
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  /**
  * toString method to get values of elements.
  * 
  * @return Returns a sentence with the values of all elements.
  */
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + getName() + ", Value: " + getValue()
        + ", Description: "
        + getDescription();
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the codes please ?

Comment: you may not have used type of item in `compareTo` method or `implements Comparable`

Comment: I have added my code above :) @SacJn

Comment: I don't see here `Comparable<Item>`

Comment: I have implemented comparable in single item it shows above @SacJn

Comment: @SacJn - Sorry I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: Does every `Item`-implementation need to implement `Compareable`? You could let `Item extend Comparable<Item>`.
If not, and your SingleItem does not need to compare to other `Item`-implementations, make it implement `Comparable<SingleItem>`.

Answer (score 0):

In short, Item doesn't implement Comparable. And the list is a list of Item.

Details here. In the code above, `items = new ArrayList<Item>();`. Which means compiler only knows that in list items, the type is Item. So when invoke `Collections.sort(items)`, java compiler found Item doesn't implement Comparable. And there will be an error as shown at the beginning.

How to fix? Change definition of Item, make it implement Comparable.

So as you can see, there is nothing about SingleItem. Because it is the impl and items sees only interface Item.